# Howto turn on/off location permission in Win Phone 8.1?

Tags: mobile, windows-phone-8

Is there a way to turn off location permission in Windows 8.1? I asked this because of a rejection from Windows Store :

App Policies: 10.5.1 Privacy Policy
If your app accesses, collects or transmits personal information, or if otherwise required by law, you must maintain a privacy policy. You must provide users with access to your privacy policy in the Description page of your app (including by submitting it to Microsoft for display to users). In addition, your privacy policy must be accessible from your app at any time. The privacy policy can be hosted within or directly linked from the app. Your privacy policy must inform users of the personal information accessed, collected or transmitted by your app and how that information is used, stored, secured and disclosed. It must describe the controls that users have over the use and sharing of their information and how they may access their information, and it must comply with applicable laws and regulations. Your privacy policy must be kept up-to-date as you add new features and functionality to your app.

Additionally, apps that receive device location must provide settings that allow the user to enable and disable the app's access to and use of location from the Location Service API. **For Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 apps, these settings must be provided in-app.** For Windows Mobile 10 apps, these settings are provided automatically by Windows within the Settings App (on the Settings->Privacy->Location page).

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean as an end user, or programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions are granted by the end user, so cannot be revoked, or set programmatically. Instead the first time you call something that requires the permission, the end user will be asked to grant access (they can later revoke this using the Location section in settings)

Comment: I asked this because of a rejection from Windows Store. Here what it says : 
Additionally, apps that receive device location must provide settings that allow the user to enable and disable the app's access to and use of location from the Location Service API. For Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone 8.1 apps, these settings must be provided in-app. For Windows Mobile 10 apps, these settings are provided automatically by Windows within the Settings App (on the Settings->Privacy->Location page).
Locations: Metadata

Comment: That requirement refers to you providing a setting within your app that your app honours - this is not about controlling anything within the OS